# What was in the weak spot on the dreadnought?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, first-order

So, in The Last Jedi we see

> a Rebel bomber destroy a First Order dreadnought by mass bombing a circle on the top of the ship

So what was that under it, that could do that? It's not near the engines. Was that

> the reactor for the big guns?

Comment: There's nothing in the Incredible Cross-Sections book that answers this, unfortunately.

Comment: There was no indication as far as I can recall that they were trying to reach that spot in particular.  I assumed the bombs were powerful enough that they just needed to be dropped anywhere close enough to the main body of the target ship.  (Anyone happen to know whether WWII bombing runs against capital vessels targeted any part of the vessel in particular?  Could be another parallel.)

Comment: FWIW, I've received advice from an expert saying "Trying to hit a ship was hard enough, hitting a specific spot didn’t really happen."

Comment: ... on the other hand, they also pointed out that a single volley wasn't going to do the job.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Not quite. Poe noted it was "almost to the sweet spot" and wondered why the bomber wasn't releasing when it was over it. They're clearly trying to hit the circle, or something in the immediate vicinity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bomber was targeting the *Fulminatrix*'s reactor:

> #### BATTLE OF D'QAR
>
> Poe Dameron leads the attack to disable the First Order dreadnought, an unmistakable fleet killer bristling with huge cannons. He flies ahead to singlehandedly take out the many anti-starfighter defenses on the dreadnought's hull, while squadrons of X-wings and A-wings escort bomber craft into their drop zones. The ponderous bombers are vulnerable to enemy fighters and many are destroyed by TIE craft. Poe's decision to continue the attack results in the loss of all but one bomber, **which delivers its entire payload onto the dreadnought's reactor**. The *Fulminatrix* erupts in flames and the Resistance fleet jumps to lightspeed.
>
> <sub>[*The Rise of Skywalker: The Visual Dictionary*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_The_Visual_Dictionary), page 22: Resistance Retreat; emphasis added</sub>

*Battles that Changed the Galaxy* elaborates on its effects on the dreadnought, though doesn't mention the reactor:

> **Dreadnought Carnage** Only a single bomber dropped its payload, but that was enough to tear the First Order dreadnought apart. As explosions stripped through the *Fulminatrix*'s hull, more than 200,000 of its crew were killed, including Captain Canady, who accepted his fate and did not try to escape.
>
> <sub>[*Battles that Changed the Galaxy*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Battles_that_Changed_the_Galaxy), page 221</sub>